# OpenResty service hangs though the ExecStart works fine

Tags: server, services, nginx

I'm using the default openresty from the standard package install on Ubuntu on GCP.

Linux bacalhau-vm-0 5.15.0-1010-gcp #15-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 10 11:30:24 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

The service file for OpenResty looks like this:

```bash
# Stop dance for OpenResty
# =========================
#
# ExecStop sends SIGSTOP (graceful stop) to OpenResty's nginx process.
# If, after 5s (--retry QUIT/5) nginx is still running, systemd takes control
# and sends SIGTERM (fast shutdown) to the main process.
# After another 5s (TimeoutStopSec=5), and if nginx is alive, systemd sends
# SIGKILL to all the remaining processes in the process group (KillMode=mixed).
#
# nginx signals reference doc:
# http://nginx.org/en/docs/control.html
#
[Unit]
Description=The OpenResty Application Platform
After=syslog.target network-online.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target
Wants=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/nginx.pid
ExecStartPre=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -t -q -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecStart=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;'
ExecReload=/usr/local/openresty/nginx/sbin/nginx -g 'daemon on; master_process on;' -s reload
ExecStop=-/sbin/start-stop-daemon --quiet --stop --retry QUIT/5 --pidfile /usr/local/openresty/nginx/logs/nginx.pid
TimeoutStopSec=5
KillMode=mixed

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run the ExecStart command from the commandline, it works just fine. But when I do `service openresty start` it hangs until timeout.

I'm not sure what else could be wrong? I've also tried setting Type to `simple` in case for some reason it wasn't forking properly, but that doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

In my nginx.conf file, i was setting the PID location to /var/run/nginx.pid.

In the openresty.services file, it has a hard coded PID location. By removing the PID location in my nginx.conf file, it worked as expected.